# ATL CComPtr Attach, Detach and Destructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, atl

I think..
Attach and Detach makes no change in the reference count.
But Destructor of CComPtr call release on the pointer it contains.

So is it necessary to call detach every time when one use attach?...

```
{
    CComPtr<IObj> pPtr;
    pPtr.Attach(pPtr1);
    .....//No detach on pPtr
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned, `Attach`/`Detach` don't affect reference counter, by design. So you are to use them when you have a special need to skip adding a reference. Otherwise you initialize the pointer in a more natural way (constructor, assignment operator etc).

Your special need for `Attach` is typically to compensate external reference already added. So that your `CComPtr` destructor would correctly release it when it is time to.

So, no, you don't have to pair `Attach` with `Detach`. When you have to, you supposedly would not use Attach in first place.

For example, `Attach`:

```cpp
{
  // We have an oustanding reference on pRawFoo we want to safely compensate for
  CComPtr pFoo;
  pFoo.Attach(pRawFoo); // No effect on counter, but since here we would release 
                        // the reference going out of scope
  // ...
} // ~CComPtr releases the reference as intended
```

No need in `Attach`:

```cpp
{
  // External pRawFoo is in proper balance in terms of reference count
  CComPtr pFoo;
  pFoo = pRawFoo; // No need in Attach, pFoo adds a reference
  // ...
} // ~CComPtr releases the reference as intended
```

Answer (score 1):

Like most smart pointers, `CComPtr<T>` indicates ownership and uses RAII semantics to ensure that an owned resource is properly cleaned up. The methods `Attach` and `Detach` are used to transfer ownership, in part because the reference count bookkeeping can be relatively expensive. So the question you need to answer in your context is what the pattern of ownership is.

When transferring ownership between two `CComPtr<T>` objects, there will be a tendency to match `Attach` and `Detach` calls, but they will be on the separate objects:

```
    spFoo2.Attach(spFoo1.Detach());
```

Consider the following snippets and what they indicate about ownership of the `IFoo` object.  Both `m_spFoo` and `spFoo` are intended to be `CComPtr<IFoo>` values:

```
HRESULT C::GetFoo_1(IFoo **ppFoo)
{
    return m_spFoo.QueryInterface(ppFoo); // or m_spFoo.CopyTo(ppFoo)
}
```

```
HRESULT C::GetFoo_2(IFoo **ppFoo)
{
    *ppFoo = m_spFoo.Detach();
    return S_OK;
}
```

```
    spFoo = obj.GetFoo_3();
```

```
    spFoo.Attach(obj.GetFoo_4());
```

Here's my take on these snippets.

- The first is a very usual way to return an `IFoo` to a caller, following the usual semantics wherein the caller receives a copy with an incremented reference count.
- The second is okay if ownership is being passed to the caller; the caller takes the copy that the `C` object previously had.
- The third is probably returning a `CComPtr<IFoo>` or `CComPtr<IFoo>&` already (the non-reference case can lead to extra reference count bookkeeping) and we are indicating further shared ownership; that is, we want to keep it around for longer than that statement.
- The fourth indicates unusual semantics in `GetFoo_4`, as it must have provided a reference count on a raw `IFoo*` that we don't want to further increment.